# Vertical alignment of the legend text in QGIS map printer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

I'm using QGIS 3.22.11-Białowieża to create a map with a point layer. Point size depends on the values of a certain attribute and, when creating the legend in the print-composer, I would like to have the text aligned to the center of each symbol. However, this is what I get:

[image]

It is more obvious in the larger symbols and I've tried changing different values within the legend properties without success. How can it be solved?

Comment: Same problem if you have a text legend on 2 lines, it is not center, just align at top! Never found a solution.

Comment: Can you share more about exactly how you generated the size based legend and how you set up your legend? I tried recreating this in QGIS 3.22.11 using Graduated Symbology and under Method selected Size, and my circles were left-aligned but the text was vertically centre-aligned... https://i.imgur.com/F2qUbjk.jpg

Comment: Difficult to say without sharing your project to see what settings you have. Can't reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: @katagena I have a solution for your problem, though it doesn't work for the original question. Please poste a new question.